# Remove Duplicates Based on ID Variable?

Tags: r, duplicates

I've got a dataset for which I'd like to remove duplicate observations based on if there is a different ID in another variable. In the following example, for anytime "id" matches for two different "coders", I would like to remove all observations for one of the coders:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3, 4, 5), coder = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), y = c(4,5,4,1,1,2,3,2, 5, 6))
df
```

In this case, I want to drop observations that match on ID if there are two different coders and only preserve those coded by "A" for those case; I would like to keep all observations for which there isn't a match. Using this rule, the dataset should look like:

```
    id     coder   y
  1  1     A       4
  2  1     A       5
  4  2     A       1
  6  3     A       2
  8  3     A       2
  9  4     B       5
  9  5     A       6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `ave` to determine if there is more than one `coder` per `id`, then use logic to require that your subset has either one `coder` per `id`, or more than one `coder` per `id` and `coder` is "A".

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3, 4, 5), 
                 coder = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), 
                 y = c(4,5,4,1,1,2,3,2, 5, 6),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
temp <- with(df, ave(coder, id, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
df[((temp == 1) | ((temp > 1) & (df$coder == "A"))), ]
```

This produces the desired result.

```
> df[((temp == 1) | ((temp > 1) & (df$coder == "A"))), ]
   id coder y
1   1     A 4
2   1     A 5
4   2     A 1
6   3     A 2
8   3     A 2
9   4     B 5
10  5     A 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[length(unique(coder))==1|coder=="A"], by=list(id)]
#   id coder y
# 1:  1     A 4
# 2:  1     A 5
# 3:  2     A 1
# 4:  3     A 2
# 5:  3     A 2
# 6:  4     B 5
# 7:  5     A 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(coder == "A" | n_distinct(coder) == 1)

#Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
#Groups: id
#
#  id coder y
#1  1     A 4
#2  1     A 5
#3  2     A 1
#4  3     A 2
#5  3     A 2
#6  4     B 5
#7  5     A 6
```